# I want NOT to escape HTML tags in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am newbie of AngularJS. I want NOT to escape HTML tags, and wrote the code below:

```
<script>
  angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', 
    $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml('<strong>foo</strong>');
    };
  ])
</script>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div>
</div>
```

The code is here, too: http://plnkr.co/edit/uqYNaoj2S8qGx4tMACcu

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Instead of doing that, use a view! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: You have typo/syntax error (controller is not well formed). See your console for errors. http://plnkr.co/edit/ruVtQK?p=preview

Comment: @SepehrFarshid - wouldn't make any difference as his code is broke anyway....

Comment: @Darren well, I just wanted to point that out. Code issues can be fixed. Design issues? That's not so easy.

Comment: Yes that's a fair comment though it doesn't address the issue he's having. How do we know he hasn't just put this together from existing code for examples sake..

Comment: Noone knows what the issue is anyway, because OP never mentioned it.

Comment: I just now returned my PC. Sorry for many comments. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why it's on hold.... doesn't take a rocket scientist to see what it is he's trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire controller block is incorrect.

instead of

`.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', 
        $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
          return $sce.trustAsHtml('<strong>foo</strong>');
        };
      ])`

It should be

`angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize'])
      .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){
        $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
          return $sce.trustAsHtml('<strong>foo</strong>');
        }
   }]);`

You don't have a `function()` declared in it for starters - which is where your injected `$scope` and `$sce` would go

Here is an updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UG2aVRovwDZ9IZr4fU9n?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm going to pay more attention to my code.